# Красивый вывод чисел в столбик

Tags: python, вывод, форматирование

У меня есть несколько вещественных чисел и я хочу *красиво* вывести их в столбик.
Под «красиво» я имею в виду, что для каждого числа должно быть выделено *одинаковое число символов* (например, `12` символов).

Если число *слишком большое* или *слишком маленькое*, то оно должно быть записано *в экспоненциальной форме*. Если число состоит из меньше чем 12 символов, то оно должно быть *дополнено слева пробелами*.

Мечтаю о таком красивом выводе чисел уже полгода как минимум.

Comment: [простой и красивый ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52650202) на похожий вопрос

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Используй модификатор `g`:

```
'{:12g}'.format(число)
```

---

Например,

```
numbers = [0, 1, 12345, .001023, 1.234567890123456789, 1.234567890123456789e-7, 1234567890123456789e+10]
for number in numbers:
    print('{:12g}'.format(number))
```

выведет:

```
           0
           1
       12345
    0.001023
     1.23457
 1.23457e-07
 1.23457e+28
```